# Google YouTube API - unattended upload

Tags: java, youtube, oauth-2.0

I'm currently trying to create an unattended application that will automate the creation and deletion of videos on a channel.

With OAuth 2.0 being the latest incarnation of the YouTube api, I'm wondering how to go about this without constant reverification of a token.

There seems to be some documentation on Google suggesting that a service account is the way forward for this, then documentation suggesting that there isn't.

https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/OAuth2#Authorization_Code_Flow

https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5370

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to how to go about this? This will be a Java application using a Scheduler Job to perform the work.

The following returns a forbidden 403 JSON exception:

```
credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
            .setTransport(httpTransport)
            .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
            .setServiceAccountId(emailAddress)
           // .setServiceAccountUser("propertypal@gmail.com")
            .setServiceAccountScopes(scopes)
            .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("D:\\Youtube\\YoutubeUploader.p12"))
            .build();
```

Any guidance on process appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant use a service account with YouTube API

[Issue 5370:   Youtube v3 Google Service Account Access](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5370)

You will need to use the normal Oauth2 method authenticate your code once.  Save your Refresh token then use that refresh toke to run from then on.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the normal 'Oauth2 method' to authenticate is?  And does it involve browser interaction to grab the first token?

Comment: Yes normal oauth2 is when the system pops up a browser you click accept and the authentication is processed and you get a refresh token back.   Unfortunately with the YouTube API this is your only option.